# Set different activity items for UIActivityViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have `UIActivityViewController` with 4 options: **Message / Mail / TW / FB**.
I want to send different activities for each option!

For eg: 
In `iMessage` sheet, I need to put : `String`, `NSURL`, and `UIImage`.
In Mail I need to place string in Subject field, then String in body, `UIImage` and `NSURL` also.
In `TW/FB`  I want to place image like socials post did it, also some String and `NSURL`.

Do you have any idea if this is possible in iOS8, with Swift ?

I searched a lot for some pieces of code, did not found the best for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should take advantage of the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. The `activityItems` parameter of the initializer of `UIActivityViewController` accepts either an array of data objects or an array of objects that implement the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol.

As an example consider an item source like the following.

```
class MyStringItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }

    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
            return "String for message"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
            return "String for mail"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
            return "String for twitter"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
            return "String for facebook"
        }
        return nil
    }

    func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: String?) -> String {
        if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
            return "Subject for message"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
            return "Subject for mail"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
            return "Subject for twitter"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
            return "Subject for facebook"
        }
        return ""
    }

    func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: String!, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage! {
        if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
            return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-message")
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
            return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-mail")
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
            return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-twitter")
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
            return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-facebook")
        }
        return UIImage(named: "some-default-thumbnail")
    }
}
```

The above item source returns different string data objects, subjects and thumbnail images based on the activity type. To use, you just need to pass it into the `UIActivityViewController` initializer.

```
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [MyStringItemSource()], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Similarly, you could define a custom `MyUrlItemSource` class that returns different URLs based on the selected activity and pass it along in the initializer.

```
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [MyStringItemSource(), MyUrlItemSource()], applicationActivities: nil)
```

All of this is outlined in the official documentation for [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivityViewController/initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:) and [`UIActivityItemSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:)

Comment: @BhaveshNai: There#s not much Swift magic involved here. Translating the above to Objective-C should be straightforward.

Comment: Writing `delegate = self` not required at all.

Comment: How would you do the last thing, "define a custom MyUrlItemSource class that returns different URLs based on the selected activity"

Comment: @user6631314: It's the same code except that you return a `URL` instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 5):

Same solution like from [hennes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303148/hennes) translated to **swift 3**

```
class MyStringItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

  public func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
    return ""
  }

  public func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
    if activityType == UIActivityType.message {
      return "String for message"
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.mail {
      return "String for mail"
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.postToTwitter {
      return "String for twitter"
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.postToFacebook {
      return "String for facebook"
    }
    return nil
  }

  public func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
    if activityType == UIActivityType.message {
      return "Subject for message"
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.mail {
      return "Subject for mail"
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.postToTwitter {
      return "Subject for twitter"
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.postToFacebook {
      return "Subject for facebook"
    }
    return ""
  }

  public func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    if activityType == UIActivityType.message {
      return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-message")
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.mail {
      return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-mail")
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.postToTwitter {
      return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-twitter")
    } else if activityType == UIActivityType.postToFacebook {
      return UIImage(named: "thumbnail-for-facebook")
    }
    return UIImage(named: "some-default-thumbnail")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C equivalent of [hennes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303148/hennes) answer:

```
@interface MyStringItemSource : NSObject <UIActivityItemSource>
{

}

@end


@implementation MyStringItemSource

-(id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
{
    return @"";
}

-(id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType
{
    if (activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage) {
        return @"String for message";
    } else if (activityType == UIActivityTypeMail) {
        return @"String for mail";
    }
    return nil;
}

-(NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType
{
    if (activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage) {
        return @"Subject for message";
    } else if (activityType == UIActivityTypeMail) {
        return @"Subject for mail";
    }
    return @"";
}

-(UIImage *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController thumbnailImageForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType suggestedSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed: @"thumbnail-for-message"];
    } else if (activityType == UIActivityTypeMail) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed: @"thumbnail-for-mail"];
    }
    return [UIImage imageNamed: @"thumbnail-for-default"];
}

@end
```