# UIActivityViewController set image later?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uikit

I'm working on an app that does some intense photo processing. It's pretty fast for small images, but it can take like 10 seconds for a full-resolution photo.

Is there any way to pull up the interface for `UIActivityViewController` before I've generated the full-resolution photo?

I'd like to do it in the following order:

1. User clicks "Share"
2. Open `UIActivityViewController`. User selects "Save to Library"
3. Display a progress bar while we generate the full resolution image and actually save it.

As far as I can tell, `UIActivityViewController`requires the image when it is initialized. Is there any way around this?

```
// this step takes 10s, can I defer it until after they choose?
let img = self.fullyRenderedImage(view)

let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img], applicationActivities: nil)

// can I present this before I have img ready?
self.presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think of [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:), set a placeHolder, and process the actual data in the background.

[Set different activity items for UIActivityViewController Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063708/set-different-activity-items-for-uiactivityviewcontroller-swift)

Comment: Update: Also see UIActivityItemProvider which allows you to create the activity item in a background thread.