# Customize URL for iOS sharing

Tags: ios

It's pretty clear to me how to share a link with [the iOS sharing activity](http://www.appcoda.com/social-framework-introduction/)... But I would like to customize the tracking in the url for different kind of shares, always using the same standard... Examples following...

Twitter:

`http://www.example.com?utm_source=TWITTER&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=socialbuttons&utm_content=app_android`

Facebook:

`http://www.example.com?utm_source=FACEBOOK&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=socialbuttons&utm_content=app_android`

Etc...

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: You need to share different `url` for **twitter** and **facebook** using `UIActivityController`.?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)

Comment: Duplicate: [Set different activity items for UIActivityViewController Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30063708/2415822)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved in Objective-C by adding a custom `UIActivityItemProvider`:

```
#import "CustomUiActivityItemProvider.h"

@implementation CustomUiActivityItemProvider

- (id)initWithText:(NSString *)text{

    if ((self = [super initWithPlaceholderItem:text])) {
        self.text = text ?: @"";
        self.url = @"";
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)item {
    NSString *activityType = self.activityType;

    if ([self.placeholderItem isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

        if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
            self.url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&utm_source=facebook", self.text];
        } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
            self.url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&utm_source=twitter", self.text];
        } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
            self.url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&utm_source=message", self.text];
        } else if([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]){
            self.url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&utm_source=email", self.text];
        } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]){
            self.url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&utm_source=weibo", self.text];
        }else{
            self.url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&utm_source=other", self.text];
        }

        return self.url;
    }

    return self.placeholderItem;
}

@end
```

And using it like this:

```
CustomUiActivityItemProvider *customProvider = [[CustomUiActivityItemProvider alloc] initWithText:urlString];


UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[customProvider]
                                                                         applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
activityVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
 // CODE.... 
}
   [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

- To do this we gonna use `UIActivityItemSource` which act as the data provider for our `UIActivityViewController`.The documentation states as follows.

> When implementing this protocol, your object becomes the data provider, providing the view controller with access to the items.

- To know more about refer this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActivityItemSource) .
- Create a `NSObject` class as follows and add it after your `UIViewController` class

  ```
  class shareDifferentUrl: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
  @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
      return ""
  }

  @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController:  UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
      if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
          return NSURL(string:"https://twitter.com/")
      } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
          return NSURL(string:"https://www.facebook.com/")
      }
      return nil
   }
  }
  ```
- That's it now just add above class as `activityItems` of your `UIActivityViewController`

  ```
  @IBAction func share(sender: AnyObject) {
     let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareDifferentUrl()] as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
     self.navigationController?.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```
- Now we can able to share different `url` for **twitter** and **fb**